# Reposition part of an STL along the surface of the main object

Tags: edit-mode, 3d-printing, stl

I want to reposition my screw holes from an STL file I found (move both holes up horizontally and opposite each other). When I try to do this in edit mode using vertices, it will leave mishaped surfaces. I've tried looking into `bisect` and `split`, but I'm not sure that's the right place too.

Any tips or links to videos about repositing part of an stl along the surface would be helpful, I found it really hard to find examples like this. I've spent about 4 hours on basic blender tutorials by Maker Tales, and I looked ahead into the playlist and wasn't able to find examples of this kind of editing.

[Link to stl.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tesd30OLJWnQoQmhyLmNoJyoPO3t40TU/view?usp=sharing)

[image: resposition hole]

Final position of the holes, but without the weird surface issues...
[image: final]

Comment: This is a bit of a complicated one. I've had a look at the model and it's not the tidiest geometry in the world. As you've seen, it's all triangulated which makes editing it hard. Depending on the purpose of this model (what you want to use it for), I'd be tempted to either delete those screw holes and make them from scratch (in a separate mesh which you later join back to the bulkhead), or cut and paste the existing ones so you can edit them separately of the main mesh - which you, again, join back later.

Comment: I have tried,but when I find out that even the circle you see in the picture is not real circle, I give up.The mesh is too bad.